# How come Window.innerWidth's value changed upon zooming in?

Tags: html, viewport

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts) seems to have contradicted itself. Here are a few statements made on the doc:

***Definition of a layout viewport:***

`The area within the innerHeight and innerWidth is generally considered the layout viewport.`

***Properties of the layout viewport:***

`When the user pinch-zooms the page, pops open a dynamic keyboard, or when a previously hidden address bar becomes visible, the visual viewport shrinks but the layout viewport is unchanged.`

***Contradiction:***

`The viewport was originally 1200 x 800 (window.innerWidth; x window.innerHeight) pixels. Upon zooming in, the viewport became 800 x 533 pixels. This is the layout viewport.`

So, they claimed the layout viewport's size cannot change upon zooming. `Window.innerWidth` is the width of the layout viewport. If `Window.innerWidth` is the width of the layout viewport, and the size of the layout viewport cannot change, how come `Window.innerWidth`'s value changed upon zooming in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, pinch-zoom on mobile is simply not the same as zooming on desktop. The zooming done via an pinch-gesture does not change the page layout. It performs the magnification effect on the page as is.